# Clicking the Short URL generated by Branch.io is not opening my iOS App

Tags: ios, branch.io

I have integrated the Branch SDK through Cocoapods in my iOS App.

Branch.io settings:

Settings -> Link Settings -> I have checked these three options,
     1. Always try to open app
     2. I have an iOSApp -> Updated the values of "iOS URI Scheme" & "Custom URL"
     3. Enable Universal Links -> Updated the values of "Bundle Identifier" & "Apple App Prefix"

Finally, I got a short URL generated by Branch.io

iOS App configuration:
 1. Added a branch_key in Info.Plist
2. Added a URL scheme in the Info.plist as,
3. Enabled the Associated Domains in the Capabilities tab & added the "applinks:bnc.lt" as an entitlement
4. Also enabled the Associated Domains in the Apple Developer portal

I have followed those above steps for integrating the branch.io in my iOS App for the deep linking to work. I have tried deployed the App through Xcode & also tried deployed the App through Adhoc provisioning. But that short URL is not opening My iOS App

Please do the needful on this issue.

Thanks,
Govindakarthikeyan

Comment: Could we see the link you are using for testing?

Comment: where are you opening the url from?

Answer (score 0):

When an app has been correctly configured for Universal Linking but Universal Links still fail to open the app, the issue is often that Universal Linking for the app has inadvertantly been disabled by the user.

Disabling Universal Linking is, unfortunately, very easy to do by mistake. When an app is opened via a Universal Link, tapping on the "bnc.lt" or "app.link" button in the upper right-hand corner of the screen, as shown in the screenshot below, will disable Universal Links for the app.

[image]

To re-enable Universal Links for an app, tap on a link from Notes and select the "Open in..." option, as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]